# Replacing memory references/addresses from a string containing <ClassName:MEM_REF> type parts

Tags: ruby

I have strings like:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'sort_by!' for #<Hash:0x00007f98f03c84e0>`

These strings **can** contain n number of such parts: `<Hash:0x00007f98f03c84e0>`.

Here, **`0x00007f98f03c84e0` is just a placeholder of memory reference. And also `Hash` is type of object of which this memory reference is.** There is no need to discuss how these strings got formed but in the end i have strings which can have anything like `<ClassName:MEM_REF>` and i have to replace `MEM_REF` part.

Going back to my original example, I want to remove this memory ref part  `0x00007f98f03c84e0` with any string of my liking. Again, `0x00007f98f03c84e0` is an example, it will be any arbitrary memory address.

Looking for an elegant way of doing this in ruby.

Comment: I think you have multiple type of memory refs in string and want to remove them, please confirm. If so i think you can use some kind of regex and i can help you build that.

Comment: What is the exact input? What is the desired output? What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, there can be multiple memory references

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin as mentioned in question, input are string. I want to replace these refs with SOMETHING. And i am still thinking what to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regex in ruby console, should work: `/:[0-9]x[0-9A-Za-z]*(?=>)/`.

And to mask these refs with anything else, try `input_string.gsub!(/:[0-9]x[0-9A-Za-z]*(?=>)/, "REPLACE_TEXT")`

Comment: Hmm, sounds good. Will try and update here

Comment: `[A-Z]`? Radix `36`?

Comment: Fyi: 0x means following are hex number, there won't be other `nx` prefix.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin didn't get your point. Can you elaborate

Comment: `0x00007f98f03c84e0` is a memory pointer, the hexadecimal number, radix 16. It can be effectively matched with `/0x[\da-f]{16}/`, or, to support different memory models, with `/0x[\da-f]{8,}(?=>)/`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin nice, you can suggest an edit in my question or if you want to post new answer. I just threw whatever i could think of and it worked, but yours is optimal i agree